# How can I hide a tab of a Shell TabBar conditionally?

Tags: maui

I have a .Net MAUI app. In AppShell, it has a TabBar:

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Home" Icon="{StaticResource IconHome}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Estimator" Icon="{StaticResource IconCalculator}" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate calculator:CoverageCalculatorPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Distributors" Icon="{StaticResource IconLocator}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate locator:DistributorsLocatorPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Scan QR" Icon="{StaticResource IconQrScanner}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate qrScanner:QrScannerPage}" />
    </Tab>        
    <Tab Title="More" Icon="{StaticResource IconMore}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate more:MoreFeaturesPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

I need to hide the "Scan QR" tab when run on Windows, and show only on iOS or Android. I realize that there is IsVisible property of Tab, but how can I make it conditional, based on the platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use class  `DeviceInfo.Platform` to get the platform information. And add a bool variable to bind to property `IsVisible` of `Tab`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
 public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
      public bool IsVisible {get;set;}

      public AppShell()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
  
            if (Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS || Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
            {
                  IsVisible = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                  IsVisible = false;
            }
            

            BindingContext = this;

      }
}
```

And bind variable `IsVisible` to property `IsVisible`:

```
    <Tab Title="Scan QR" Icon="grass.png" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:QrScannerPage}" />
    </Tab>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I just had to rename IsVisible variable, as it already exists in that scope.