# Does anyone know how to generate multiple tabs in the shell? It is implemented according to the collection rather than fixed

Tags: maui

I want to implement tab dynamically, but I can't find the relevant part in the MAUI document.

I hope it can be implemented in xmal, like listview. Or c # code.

Comment: Use can use the IsVisible property of tabs to hide and unhide them.

Comment: @Paramjit  maybe this can https://github.com/simphonydeveloper/MauiShellTabExample

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `IsVisible`  property of tabs to achieve this just as Paramjit said.

You can refer to the following code:

```
 public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
      public bool IsVisibleTab {get;set;}

      public AppShell()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
  
            if (Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS || Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
            {
                  IsVisibleTab = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                  IsVisibleTab = false;
            }
            

            BindingContext = this;

      }
}
```

And bind variable `IsVisibleTab`  to property `IsVisible`:

```
<Tab Title="Test" Icon="icon.png" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleTab }">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:YourPage}" />
</Tab>
```

**Note:**

You can change the `if-else` to your conditional statements.

Reference: [How can I hide a tab of a Shell TabBar conditionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74621532/how-can-i-hide-a-tab-of-a-shell-tabbar-conditionally/74622386#74622386).

Comment: This is my idea https://github.com/simphonydeveloper/MauiShellTabExample